# How to import django data from windows on ubuntu correctly?

Tags: python, django, linux, windows

I am moving the django page from the windows server to the ubuntu server. I get a utf8 error while executing the `python manage.py loaddata` command. Unfortunately, I don't know why. Below I send the message I receive.

**'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte**

I will add that the site uses the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the encoding in the file I imported from. I did this using the notepad ++ code editor.